# Wikipedia API search by relevancy

Tags: php, search, wikipedia-api

When I fire a POST/GET request with the following parameters, the API returns search result sorted by relevancy

```
array(
  'format' => 'json',
  'action' => 'query',
  'list' => 'search',
  'srsearch' => $query
);
```

example GET :
`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=search&srsearch=bose+einstein+condensate`

If you go to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/search or
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/search, and enter the '**boss** einstein condensate', instead of '**bose** einstein condensate', it shows relevant suggestions. But if I do the same with the API, it returns irrelevant results.

Is there a way to get those suggestions from the API?